# Can I use quotation marks to mean a word is used euphemistically?

Tags: punctuation, usage, quotation-marks

In Italian I could write *Ho visto "l'albergo" dove lavori.* (*I saw the "hotel" where you work.*) In that sentence, I am not quoting what somebody said, but I am using *albergo* in an euphemistic way, probably because I don't want to really call with its name what I have seen.

Is it possible to do the same in English, or should I use something different? In the latter case, what should I write instead of *I saw the "hotel" where you work*?

Comment: kiam, I think the sentence is more euphemistic this way *I saw the hotel where you "work"*, no?

Comment: In that case, the meaning would be different: It means the person doesn't do much for work, or avoids doing anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the punctuation as in *I saw the "hotel" where you work.* works in English as well as in Italian; according to wikipedia's *[Scare Quotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes)* article,

> Scare quotes are quotation marks placed around a word or phrase to imply that **it may not signify its apparent meaning** or that it is not necessarily the way the quoting person would express its concept. Thus, the quotes are used to establish a use–mention distinction, **in a similar way as verbally prefixing a phrase with "so-called"**. When referred to as "scare quotes", the quotation marks are suggested to imply skepticism or disagreement with the quoted terminology.

(Emphases added.)

Comment: One thing I'll add: You can use scarce quotes, or you can use _so-called_, but you shouldn't use both in combination. In other words, you would **not** say: _I saw the so-called "hotel" where you work._

Comment: I learned something new: I didn't know what _scare quotes_ would mean. I would have thought of quotes from horror movies. `;)`